# 幸い Usage with Particles (~で or ~に)

Tags: particles

I'm trying to write a phrase that says "Fortunately I passed (the exam)" and I would like to use 幸い in it, but I'm not sure how I would go about writing it, mainly because I'm not quite sure which particle to use together with 幸い. In my vision there are 2 options:

```
幸いに合格した
```

or

```
幸いで合格した
```

I'm more inclined to say that the first option is the right one, but both could be wrong or the second option could be the right one. I would appreciate some insight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「[幸]{さいわ}い**に**」 is the correct form and another possibility is 「幸い**にも**」.

「幸い**で**」 is incorrect.

You will see/hear 「幸いです」、「幸いである」、「幸いでした」, etc., but the 「で」 is not a particle in any of those phrases.